# $ds=\frac{2|dz|}{1-|z|^2}$ conformal invariant of the disc.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose $w$, $z$, $w_0$ and $z_0$ are in the unit disc $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C} \ \big| \ |z| =1\}$ and satisfy $$\left| \frac{w-w_0}{1-\bar{w_0}w} \right| = \left| \frac{z-z_0}{1-\bar{z_0}z} \right|. $$ How do you show that $$ \frac{1-|w_0|^2}{|z_0|^2} = \frac{1-|w|^2}{1-|z|^2} \ ?$$ (This is --I assume-- to prove that the expression $ds=\frac{2|dz|}{1-|z|^2}$ is a conformal invariant of the disc (John Garnett's book *Bounded analytic functions*, page 4)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that equation (1.12) in the book you cited is incorrect. Indeed, as he noted there, if $w$ is a Mobius transformation which sends $z_0$ to $w_0$ then $$\frac{w(z)-w_0}{1-\overline{w_0}w(z)}=e^{i\varphi}\frac{z-z_0}{1-\overline{z_0}z}\tag{1}$$

By taking modulus in both sides of $(1)$ and dividing by $|z-z_0|$ we conclude that $$\frac{|w(z)-w_0|}{|z-z_0|}\frac{1}{|1-\overline{w_0}w(z)|}=\frac{1}{|1-\overline{z_0}z|}\tag{2}$$

If we let $z\to z_0$ in $(2)$ we obtain $$\frac{|w'(z_0)|}{1-|w_0|^2}=\frac{1}{1-|z_0|^2}$$

which is sufficiently to prove that the metric $$\frac{2|dz|}{1-|z|^2}$$

is conformally invariant.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. How do you show that the correct formula is sufficient to prove the invariance? Do we need to show that $\frac{1-|z_0|^2}{1-|z|^2}=\frac{1-|w_0|^2}{1-|w|^2}$ first? (If so, how?)

Comment: You are welcome. Before answering your question, let me first make a question. What do you have to do in order to show that the metric in conformally invariant?

Comment: The book doesn't explicitly mention what is conformal invariance, so my guess is it means that if $z$ and $w$ are related to each other by a Mobius transform then $\frac{2|dz|}{1-|z|^2}=\frac{2|dw|}{1-|w|^2}$. I don't know if I'm interpreting correctly, but if I am, then we need to show that $\frac{1-|z_0|^2}{1-|z|^2}=\frac{1-|w_0|^2}{1-|w|^2}$, right?

Comment: Let $f:D\to D$ be a diffeomorphism. For eaxh fized $z$, $f'(z)$ is a linear transformation which sends vectors from the tangente plane on $z$ to the tangente plane on $f(z)$. We say that $f$ is conformal with respect to the metric $ds=\frac{2|dz|}{1-|z|^2}$, if $f'(z)$ preserve angles between vectors, where the angles are measured with the metric $ds$. What Garnett did in the book was to show that $w$ do more than that, in fact, $w$ preserves lengths of vectors, which is the last equality in my answer. Do you understood?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I'm afraid I don't understand yet. For instance, how do you (in practice) compute the angle between two (tangent) vectors measured by the metric $ds$? And same question for the lengths. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: There is no problem @Weltschmerz. Let me see if I can explain it to you. The symbol $|dz|$ is defined by $|dz|^2=dx^2+dy^2$ and this is jut the usual inner product of $\mathbb{R}^2$, i.e. $|dz|^2(u,v)=dx^2(u,v)+dy^2(u,v)= u_1v_1+u_2v_2=\langle u,v\rangle$ where $u=(u_1,u_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $v=(v_1,v_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2$. For each point $x\in D$ where $D=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:\ \|x\|<1\}$, the tangent space in $x$ is by indentification $\mathbb{R}^2$. When you fix $z=a+bi$ with $|z|<1$, you are taking $(a,b)\in D$. The metric $ds^2$ says that (continue...)

Comment: in the point $z$, your inner product is defined by $\frac{4|dz|^2}{(1-|z|^2)^2}$ and this is saying that if you take tangent vectors, let's say $u,v$, in the tangent plane of $(a,b)$ then their angle are measured as follows $$ds^2(u,v)=\frac{4|dz|^2(u,v)}{(1-|z|^2)^2}=\frac{4\langle u,v\rangle}{(1-|z^2|)^2}$$ where $\langle u,v\rangle$ is as I said above, the usual inner product in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Now, to say that $ds$ is conformally invariant is the same to say that, if $S$ is a conformal map then $$\frac{4\langle S'(z)u,S'(z)v\rangle }{(1-|S(z)|^2)^2}=\frac{4\langle u,v\rangle }{(1-|z|^2)^2},\ \forall z\in D,\ \forall u,v\mathbb{R}^2$$